# SQL Server 2000 trace file extension

Tags: sql-server-2000, trace

Are SQL Server 2000 trace files generated in a `.tdf` format, the same way as SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: I think it's `.trc` (at least for SQL Server **2005** and newer) - but I quite honestly don't remember what the ancient 2000 version used.... (too long ago)

Comment: too right! it definitely is quite ancient, but unfortunately some people still stick to it....which makes life harder for us :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL server 2000 trace file generated in .trc format for more details please refer below link
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277388.aspx